# How can I use "Raleway" font in python matplotlib?

Tags: python

How can I use the "Raleway" font in python matplotlib library?
I already installed the font on downloaded the font and I put it in the right directory, but all my tries didn't pan out.

```
plt.title("\nFemale Vs Male Participation Per City Without SPAM\n\n",y=1.44,fontdict={'fontweight':'normal','fontsize':24,},color='#7637a8',
      fontname='Raleway',loc='center')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the suggestions here: https://scentellegher.github.io/visualization/2018/05/02/custom-fonts-matplotlib.html.

Specifically, ensure your font is has type `.ttf` available, and try clearing the Matplotlib cache.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally, it works!! Just a small note, I closed the Juypter notebook until I delete the cash file successfully.

Comment: Great! Consider accepting this answer if it solved the problem. :)